# Who translated the Torah into each of the 70 languages?

Tags: translation, rashi, language, pentateuch-chumash, ki-tavo

In [Devarim 27:8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9617&st=&pgnum=330&hilite=), the Torah says to "write all the words of the Torah explained well" (- "Ba'aer Hetev".

Rash"i, citing Sotah 35b, says that this was translated into 70 languages. Sifsei Chachamim elaborates that this was done so that the nations of the world could make copies. Also, see [Why translate Torah to 70 languages](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2122/why-translate-torah-to-70-languages)

When Joshua and the Jews crossed the Jordan River and camped in Gilgal, they wrote the Torah on stones, as Moshe had commanded them in Devarim.

Related questions:

Did they translate the Torah at that time?
Was it done by one person or several people? Who knew all 70 languages?
How did they get all 70 language translations of the whole Torah on 12 stones?

Comment: I must admit, this is a first for me ... This Q has been up for about 3 days, and not even a comment by anyone! What, I created a shocker???

Comment: I actually upvoted (strange that there's only one...) but it could be that people aren't taking the question seriously because it's a midrash agadah which may not be meant to be interpreted literally (as per Ksav VehaKabbala's interpretation)

Comment: (I didn't see the question till just now.) What are the nations going to do with copies, anyway?

Comment: @DoubleAA - Good question. Then again, somehow, many years later, the GReeks and Romans figured out something from SOME language. Maybe it was from the Chinese version? :-o

Comment: This is a great question, and I wonder why you accepted the answer, as it seems illogical, e.g.: **1.** learning Torah is forbidden for gentiles, **2** Tagin only apply to a Kosher Sefer Torah, you don't write Halokhos with Tagin, **3** this transgresses "לא תעשו כן לה'" as the stones can be smashed, **4** Sages testified Torah can not be translated (but to Greek?), **5** What the translation into 70 help the Jews to understand Torah  באר היטב? and many more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be on the sanhedrin one requirement was knowledge of all 70 languages. Moshe Rabbeinu was shakul kineged beis din shel shivim (equal to a 70-member court of law), so off the bat I'm willing to assume he knew all 70 (as it was required to know all 70 languages to be a member of the Sanhedrin). Plus we know that Yosef knew all 70, so its likely the knowledge was passed along from him to any number of people. 
As far as fitting on 12 stones, I think the Ramban (?) says it was a neiss (miracle). Or a condensed version according to another pirush. Sorry, not near any sfarim right now.

**Edit**. I will quote the Ramban on the pasuk.

> R' Avraham, (ibn Ezra) says in the name of the gaon that they wrote
>   the list of mitzvos, such as what is written in the Halachos Gidolos,
>   the words ba'er heitev mean the writing. Our Rabbis (Sota [32a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=18&daf=32&format=pdf)) say it
>   means it was translated into seventy languages. And it's found in the
>   seffer tagi that the whole torah was written on them from Breishis
>   until "einei kol yisroel" with its tagin and zayonin(?) and from there
>   they took tagin for the whole Torah. And it's plausible that the stones
>   were extremely large or it was a maaseh nissim'.

Comment: When you do get near sfarim please remember to come back and improve this post.

Comment: Better....I edited your answer for clarity but....whose translation is that? Give credit where credit is due.

Comment: My translation.

Comment: @user6591 or Shokhet (with an edited answer, it's unclear to me who gets what credit :-) - Can you clarify who said what you quoted? The title says Ramban, but you begin with the words "R' Avraham (Ibn Ezra). Also, please clarify the location (verse) where this is located. I also see the question mark on "zayonim". I have the same reaction as you. What are "zayonim"?

Comment: The ramban which is on passuk 3 started off by quoting the ibn ezra. I guess when he 'edited' for 'clarity' it became less clear.

Comment: I don't think the lack of clarity was a result of the edit.  Fixing your basic grammar and adding in spaces for paragraphs didn't make it confusing.

Comment: I think in my original version it was much clearer that i was quoting the Ramban verbatim. As attested to by the fact that the grumpy editor accused me of plagiarizing the translation.

Comment: ziyunim, refers to the little zayins on top of  שעטנז גץ

Comment: Man. Just found it in menachos 29b. I got all excited to post it and i find you beat me to it! Ashrei chelkicha!

Comment: But now the question is if rashi explains zayin means tagin, then how could the ramban mention them both next to each other as if they are two different items. Does he disagree with Rashi?

Comment: @user6591 - Nice thorough answer. Mazal Tov - Bounty awarded. I can't issue a certificate for you to put on your fridge :-(

Comment: @BoruchTkatch - User6591 has a point, which was why I asked about what the "zayonim" are. Is Ramba"m the only one using this term? I've never seen it used elsewhere, and your definition usually goes along with "Tagin".

Comment: The zayanim are little zayins on those letters. If you look at them you will see they look like zayins. Many other letters have tagin, such as the beis or the daled, which do not look like zayins.

Comment: @DanF- Thank! I'll put your praise al luach libi:)

Comment: @Boruch Tkatch- halachicly, the shapes on top of the shatniz getz letters and the other letters are all called tagin. The only difference is shatnez getz have three and the others have one.

Comment: @Baruch Tkatch- but your point is a good one and i'm willing to assume the ramban used a different naming system. Do they really look different though?

Comment: @user6591 I thought they looked different, but i guess i don't know for sure, especially now that you cast doubt on it. Hmm... the three are different sizes, aren't they? That would be a difference.

Comment: @user6591 I asked my neighbor the sofer about this. He told me the zayanim and tagin were indeed the same, but, the MB 36:16, right at the end, before : משנת סופרים writes: כתב בספר איגרת הטיול שעטנ"ז הוא אותיות שט"ן ע"ז והם ב' מקטרגים גדולים וזהו ג"כ סוד של שעטנ"ז ג"ץ כי ג"ץ ג"כ שם מקטרג אחד והתגין שעליהם הם כמו חרב וחנית להנצל מהם. He continued that his rebbi in safrus told him that "zayin" was from the term "klei zayin". This seems like it is not the simple translation, but it works out pretty well.

Comment: 6591 and DanF -- if you want to know what an edit did, you can click on the "[edited by](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/43333/revisions)" link under the question. If you want to get someone's attention, Dan, ping him in the comments by putting the `@` symbol in front of his name, like this: @DanF [Even though you put my name in the comments, I only saw those comments now because someone else answered this question....]